# open source photo album software?

Tags: open-source, interop, spreadsheet, photo-management

I have a friend who had been using a proprietary photo album product and reached a hard limit on the number of photos.  He managed to export the data to spreadsheet format (including image filenames) plus he of course saved the image files themselves.  He says there doesn't seem to be any other product that can import this format.

Is there any open source photo album software (preferably on Windows) that would be easy to modify to allow it to import this spreadsheet data?  Or is there perhaps another solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Maybe belongs on superuser.com?

Comment: No because I am envisioning a development effort as a solution.  I would probably also submit my work as a patch.

Comment: I'm very interested in developing a standard format/protocol for photo album software, so you can migrate the DB between programs, or access some kind of "photo server" from multiple programs *at the same time*. My immediate use case is letting every member of the family (using different operating systems) access years of vacation pictures and help tag/organize.

Comment: @Nicolas: wrote in wrong place. Should go to steven below. Removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the IPTC/XMP image metadata. If the files don't already have the right metadata, you might be able to add it from your spreadsheet using something like http://www.exiv2.org/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_gallery_software (See IPTC support column)

Answer (score 1):

Phraseanet is Open Source now, the version 3.1 has just been released. It's a professional application for Windows/Mac/Linux. You can try it (ask a demo access on www.alchemy.fr) or download it for free here: http://www.phraseanet.com/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

[Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) is a well known PHP solution to host an photo album. Its open source and in PHP, so I don't believe it would be that difficult to add an importing component into it. Also, it is based on a database, which means that you can import the data from the spreadsheet (as a CSV file) directly into the hosting database.

Comment: Thanks, but my friend wants a desktop solution, not web-based

Answer (score 0):

Under windows I use [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) and under Linux I use [Digikam](http://www.digikam.org/) and [KPhotoAlbum](http://www.kphotoalbum.org/).

Edit: Digikam now [available for Windows](http://www.digikam.org/drupal/node/378).

Comment: Nope, but it is free and I didn't hit picture limit yet (ca. 20k). However I'm anxiously waiting for KDE4 to work properly under Windows so I can have Digikam there :)

Comment: OK, but if you see the question, I specifically need the source code, because I need to modify it

Comment: Sure but for only one reason: to be able to import your data. Maybe it is possible to do with Picasa?

Otherwise you can have Digikam under Windows: http://www.digikam.org/drupal/node/378